# No logro mostrar una imagen con php

Tags: php, html

Este es mi código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    require("datos_conexion.php");
    $conexion=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_contra);
    if(!$conexion) {
        echo "Fallo al conectar con la BBDD";
        exit();
    }
    mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die ("No se encuentra la base de datos");
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
    $consulta="SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE CÓDIGOARTÍCULO='AR01'";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
    while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {

        $ruta_img=$fila["FOTO"];
    }
?>  

<div>

    <img src="/pildoras/uploads/<?php echo $ruta_img;?>" alt="Imagen del primer artículo" width="25%">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo tengo el `Github`: https://github.com/ashcrimson/pildorasinformaticas/blob/master/imagenes_servidor/leer_imagen_bbdd.php

Tengo la siguiente línea:

```
<img src="/pildoras/uploads/<?php echo $ruta_img;?>" alt="Imagen del primer artículo" width="25%">
```

Por alguna razón el navegador no lee la parte de php y entonces la ruta de la imagen queda como `<img src="/pildoras/uploads/"`

Debe ser un error de sintaxis super tonto, ¿cómo lo arreglo?

Comment: te recomiendo dejar de lado las tildes y demás acentos especiales

Answer (score 1):

Primero revisa que lo que tienes en `$fila["FOTO"]` sea el nombre correcto, es decir imprimelo en pantalla o haz un `var_dump`.

Luego revisa que la ruta sea la correcta y quita la primera barra de la ruta.

Comment: while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
  
  $ruta_img=$fila["FOTO"];

  echo $fila["FOTO"];

 }

No imprime nada.

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví, ahora funciona. Este es el código:

https://github.com/ashcrimson/pildorasinformaticas/blob/master/imagenes_servidor/leer_imagen_bbdd.php

Comment: podrías editar tanto tu pregunta como tu respuesta insertando el código por favor?